# Python BeautifulSoup to extract table from saved HTML webpages

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, extract

I'm trying to extract data from saved HTML webpages using Python 2.7 + Windows.

There are multiple saved HTML webpages, which are similar and each contains a table of 5 columns. The number of rows is not fixed.

The source code looks like:

```
text = '''

<table id="MainTable" class="KTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="KGI"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr><tr id="ASPxJ1_DXGroupRowExp0" class="KGroupRow">
                <td class="K"><img class="dxJ_gvExpandedButton" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_19-RP" alt="[Collapse]"></td><td class="K" colspan="5">Supplier Code  (Count=6, <span class="grid_sumlabel">Record Count:</span><span class="grid_sumdata">86</span>) (next page)</td>
            </tr><tr id="Row1" class="row_data">
                <td class="IndentD">Â&nbsp;</td><td class="apv"><a class="dxeHyperlink" href="admin.aspx">3617</a></td><td class="class0">German</td><td class="apv">EU</td><td class="apv" align="right">2012</td><td class="apv" align="right">2013</td>
            </tr><tr id="Row2" class="row_data row_dataAlt aspxgridAltStyle">
                <td class="IndentD">Â&nbsp;</td><td class="apv"><a class="dxeHyperlink" href="admin.aspx">3617</a></td><td class="class0"><a href="ad.aspx">Belgium</a></td><td class="apv">EU</td><td class="apv" align="right">2014</td><td class="apv" align="right">2015</td>
            </tr><tr id="Row3" class="row_data">
                                                        …
                                                        …
                                                        …
                                                        …
                                                        …
            </tr><tr id="Row50" class="row_data">
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>


'''
```

What I want is to take the table contents and put/save them in .xls files.

What I do is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
aa = soup.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all('tr')

for a in aa:
    print a.text
```

it gives all the contents but all in 1 line.

I tried:

```
aa = soup.find_all(id = 'MainTable')

for a in aa:
    for b in a.find_all(id = 'Row2'):
        print b.text
```

it gives the contents of specific row but still in 1 line.

```
3617BelgiumEU20142015
```

This isn't sufficient and uncertain rows in the html file is a problem too.

What I want is the “3617”, “Belgium”, “EU”, “2014” and “2015” separately so that I can save them in .xls files.

What’s the best way to extract the table nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate over `td` elements for each row:

```
for row in soup.select("table#MainTable tr[id^=Row]"):
    for cell in row.find_all("td"):
        print cell.text
```

Note that I'm using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to locate the table rows.

Comment: sir alecxe. many thanks for the lesson, and the link. this's definitely a good learning. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your second try, you can try `find_all` to get all `<td>` inside each row and then loop over them printing their text -

```
>>> aa = soup.find_all(id = 'MainTable')
>>> for a in aa:
...     for b in a.find_all(id = 'Row2'):
...        for c in b.find_all('td'):
...           print(c.text)
...
A 
3617
Belgium
EU
2014
2015
```

Comment: thanks, Anand S Kumar. this's helpful. hope you don'd mind I choose another another answer solve all rows.

Comment: Yea, its fine, that is a better answer for sure so you should choose it only.

Answer (score 0):

`find_all()` can search all texts using parameter `text=True`

```
e.find_all(text=True)
```

On your code

```
aa = soup.find_all(id = 'MainTable')
for a in aa:
    for b in a.find_all(id = 'Row2'):
        print b.find_all(text=True)
```

will print below:

```
[u'\n', u'\xc2\xa0', u'3617', u'Belgium', u'EU', u'2014', u'2015', u'\n']
```

Note that `\n` is also `text` so you should modify your data to not have `\n` or filter it out.

Comment: thanks, mrorno. this's helpful too. hope you don'd mind I choose another another answer solve all rows.